# Cannot get django dashing example to work

Tags: python, django, dashing

I followed the instructions here (https://github.com/talpor/django-dashing) a few times, but I never seem to be able to get the dashboard.
All I get is the screenshot attached.[image: what I get]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. This was due to using django 1.9.
When I downgraded back to 1.8 problem was solved.